# webrtc: createAnswer works on chrome but fires an error with firefox

Tags: webrtc

```
function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null, pc_constraints);
    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
    pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
      return;
  }

  try {
      // Reliable Data Channels not yet supported in Chrome
      sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel",
        {reliable: false});
      sendChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
      trace('Created send data channel');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to create data channel. ' +
            'You need Chrome M25 or later with RtpDataChannel enabled');
      trace('createDataChannel() failed with exception: ' + e.message);
    }
    sendChannel.onopen = handleSendChannelStateChange;
    sendChannel.onclose = handleSendChannelStateChange;
    pc.ondatachannel = gotReceiveChannel;
}

    function doAnswer() {
      console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
      pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, sdpConstraints);
    }
```

I got error:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 of mozRTCPeerConnection.createAnswer is not an object.
```

Comment: Are both of the browsers FireFox? What are your SDP constraints?

Comment: Does it work when you provide a failure callback like the `createAnswer` definition demands?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work in Firefox:

```
function doAnswer() {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');

  pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateAnswerError, sdpConstraints);
}

function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
  sessionDescription.sdp = preferOpus(sessionDescription.sdp);
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);

  console.log('setLocalAndSendMessage sending message' , sessionDescription);

  sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}

function handleCreateAnswerError(error) {
  console.log('createAnswer() error: ', e);
}
```

The reason why this fails in Firefox can be found in the [documentation for `createAnswer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#createAnswer). The issue is that Firefox won't let you pass null for the error handler.  All this requires is that you write your own and then pass it into `createAnswer`.  Don't pass null, you should actually be passing a function (object) to do something with the error.

Sorry for the late response, better late than never!

Answer (score 0):

how about this? Its what the guys @ xsockets use...

```
pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage,function (ex) { self.onerror(ex); }, sdpConstraints);
```